# C# OpenTK - simple example not rendering

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'm using OpenTK to create a graphics engine, but it doesn't want to draw anything.
Clearing the screen works, also swapping the buffers, but when I try to draw a rectangle using a vertex array or legacy OpenGL it won't work.

I've reproduced the problem in this small test program:

```
private static GameWindow window;
private static int vao;
private static int vbo;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    window = new GameWindow();
    window.Load += Window_Load;
    window.RenderFrame += Window_RenderFrame;
    window.Run();
}

private static void Window_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    vao = GL.GenVertexArray();
    GL.BindVertexArray(vao);
    vbo = GL.GenBuffer();
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
    GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, new IntPtr(3), new float[] {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f
    }, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
    GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0, 0);
}

private static void Window_RenderFrame(object sender, FrameEventArgs e)
{
    GL.ClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 6);
    window.SwapBuffers();
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: You aren't telling it what color the vertices are.

Comment: I don't need to I think.. It has worked without specifying the colors. I'll try it though, was working in Java before

Comment: Ok that works now, but not in my original code.. Investigation time.
Can you still post that as an answer?

Comment: To draw vertices, the rendering pipeline needs to know what color they are and where they are in space, as well as the world, projection, and view matrices in order to map them onto the 2D viewport.  Your quoted code doesn't set up anything except the vertex positions; my guess is that something taken for granted isn't happening the way you expect (e.g. in the `GameWindow` constructor) on different platforms.

Comment: Oh wait.. I didn't specify the colors now either, I used immediate mode. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Ah.  That's the thing, then.  When immediate mode is off, you have to have glBegin() and glEnd() calls to tell the pipeline to actually do what you told it to do.  I'm assuming the `GameWindow` constructor is setting up everything else for you.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to make the context forward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

A simple rendering pipeline needs some basic information to draw vertices:

- It needs to know where they are in space
- It needs to know their color or material
- It needs to know the matrices for mapping 3D space onto a 2D viewport

Your code doesn't specify any of that except for the vertex locations.  There are a number of reasons why your triangles might not be visible:

- The vertices are in the wrong order and backface culling is turned on
- The vertex color is the same as the background color
- The triangles are outside the view volume

Comment: ...I just did some research and turns out my memory is faulty; that paragraph is wrong.  Editing...

Comment: ok thanks for your help anyway :) Can't set the question to solved though sadly, cause I need to use modern OpenGL

Comment: Solved it. The context needs to be forward compatible